# How to create dates from two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a graph that shows the sales over time for 4 stores. Each row is a same and it has a month column which is ('jan','feb'...etc) and a year column which is just the year. The problem is that I have to show monthly sales so without a combined month/year column this is impossible.

I've tried creating a dictionary to assign each month a numerical value 1-12 and then create a new column called month_number using mapping. When I tried this, every value for `jan` showed up as `NaN`. My goal is to create a column of date-time objects using a for loop and then use that column for the x-axis.

```
months={'jan':1,'feb':2,'mar':3,'apr':4,'may':5,'jun':6,'jul':7,'aug':8,'sep':9,'oct':10,'nov':11,'dec':12}

sales['date_no']=sales['Month'].map(months)
print(sales['date_no'].unique())
```

> > [nan  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12.]

This is the unique values for the new column. I'm not sure why it's separating with periods. If there is an easier way to do what I'm trying to accomplish I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: There was a space in the original file each time Jan is written so that's why it came up Null.

Comment: So is your issue solved, or do you still need help with something else? If so close the question.